# How to retrieve Slack messages via API identified by permalink?

Tags: slack-api

I'm trying to retrieve a list of Slack reminders, which works fine using Slack API's `reminders.list` method. However, reminders that are set using SlackBot (i.e. by asking Slackbot to remind me of a message) return the respective permalink of that message as `text`:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "reminders": [
        {
            "id": "Rm012C299C1E",
            "creator": "UV09YANLX",
            "text": "https:\/\/team.slack.com\/archives\/DUNB811AM\/p1583441290000300",
            "user": "UV09YANLX",
            "recurring": false,
            "time": 1586789303,
            "complete_ts": 0
        },
```

Instead of showing the permalink, I'd naturally like to show the message I wanted to be reminded of. However, I couldn't find any hints in the Slack API docs on how to retrieve a message identified by a permalink. The  link is presumably generated by `chat.getPermalink`, but there seems to be no obvious `chat.getMessageByPermalink` or so.

I tried to interpet the path elements as `channel` and timestamp, but the timestamp (transformed from the example above: `1583441290.000300`) doesn't seem to really match. At least I don't end up with the message I expected to retrieve when passing this as `latest` to `conversations.history` and `limit`ing to `1`.

Answer (score 2):

After fiddling a while longer, here's how I finally managed in JS:

```
async function downloadSlackMsgByPermalink(permalink) {
  const pathElements = permalink.substring(8).split('/');
  const channel = pathElements[2];

  var url;
  if (permalink.includes('thread_ts')) {
    // Threaded message, use conversations.replies endpoint
    var ts = pathElements[3].substring(0, pathElements[3].indexOf('?'));
    ts = ts.substring(0, ts.length-6) + '.' + ts.substring(ts.length-6);

    var latest = pathElements[3].substring(pathElements[3].indexOf('thread_ts=')+10);
    if (latest.indexOf('&') != -1) latest = latest.substring(0, latest.indexOf('&'));

    url = `https://slack.com/api/conversations.replies?token=${encodeURIComponent(slackAccessToken)}&channel=${channel}&ts=${ts}&latest=${latest}&inclusive=true&limit=1`;
  } else {
    // Non-threaded message, use conversations.history endpoint
    var latest = pathElements[3].substring(1);
    if (latest.indexOf('?') != -1) latest = latest.substring(0, latest.indexOf('?'));
    latest = latest.substring(0, latest.length-6) + '.' + latest.substring(latest.length-6);
    url = `https://slack.com/api/conversations.history?token=${encodeURIComponent(slackAccessToken)}&channel=${channel}&latest=${latest}&inclusive=true&limit=1`;
  }
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const result = await response.json();
  if (result.ok === true) {
    return result.messages[0];
  }
}
```

It's not been tested to the latest extend, but first results look alright:

- The trick with the `conversations.history` endpoint was to include the `inclusive=true` parameter
- Messages might be threaded - the separate endpoint `conversations.replies` is required to fetch those
- As the Slack API docs state: `ts` and `thread_ts` look like timestamps, but they aren't. Using them a bit like timestamps (i.e. cutting off some characters at the back and inserting a dot) seems to work, gladly, however.
- Naturally, the `slackAccessToken` variable needs to be set beforehand

I'm aware the way to extract & transform the URL components in the code above might not the most elegant solution, but it proves the concept :-)

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I went googling looking for the answer to this exact question, and voilà!

Comment: Be aware that this logic doesn't account for sharing of thread messages, if try to resolve a thread message like this you'll end up with the message that was nearest to whenever the thread update was posted